# Override dll config

Tags: c#, app-config

i have a class library, with domain objects (linq based objects, in .net 
4.0).
i want to have this library use connection strings for its own app.config.

there are some problems:
following the model used by Settings : **ApplicationSettingsBase**, i created a 
wrapper that should read the settings from app.config.

however, unlike the model, i provide default values.
the problem is that the properties which should load the data from app.config

```
  internal sealed class ApplicationSettings : ApplicationSettingsBase
    {
    // other properties

        [SpecialSetting( SpecialSetting.ConnectionString )]
       [global::System.Configuration.DefaultSettingValueAttribute("Server=.;Database=RFPLUSSTD;User Id=SYSADM;Password=SYSADM;")]
        public string MainConnectionString
    {
    get { return (string)this["MainConnectionString"]; }
    }
```

// other properties
}

```
in app.config:
<connectionStrings>
<add name="MainConnectionString"
connectionString="..."
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

now, this doesn't work...
i tried to set the name of the conn string to the fully qualified name like 
namespace.class.property, but to avail.

- i don't want to use the default Settings class, used by the dbml because 
  it compiles the settings :D and i can't change them without recompiling...
- i'm already using a different model of app settings class in a project in 
  1.1, but i thought 3.5 has grown enough and have its own objects, that 
  work..

So, why is not working and how can i make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Which project is loading the connection string and how does it load it? Also how exactly are you modifying the connection string in project A?

Comment: You might need to provider more details. If this is a project using something like the entity framework, you will find that there are different constructors to set a connection string when instantiating your datacontext.

Comment: yes,it is a asp.net app, B Project use ConnString.Settings file to set default connectstring,but it is compiled,the A Project cannot modify the connString any more.

Comment: You can get some idea by checking out this video at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=juBDM3fb-i0

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that you have permissions in the file system to make the change. I hope you have considered that. If you are sure that you changed the config file and if it only brings the default settings, it might be loading the config file from output bin folder not in the project root. If you are sure that the modification fails, please post the error message.

**Updated:**

Hi Jack, I think the main issue with your code is that it is creating new instance of the ApplicationSettings class every time  and if the setting is in user scope, you will be having null value and then it results to default value every time.

You could easily do it with the built in Settings class. By default the Settings can only be accessed within the Assembly, **internal sealed partial class Settings** (in **Settings.Designer.cs**). If you change this to **public sealed** you will be able to access the Settings from any assembly and the next thing is you have to keep the setting to Application Scope not User scope.   Once you have done these two, you can retrieve and save without any problem.

Comment: sure,it has sufficient permissions.the config file is in bin folder root, when run the app, it show the default connString,not my config

Comment: it is does not relate to internal sealed partial class settings change to public .